# Can i make imported function global in python?

Tags: python

I have something like this:

```
from CoreTemplate import CoreTemplate
```

when i want to use the imported function from CoreTemplate Module I need to do like this:

```
CoreTemplate.ifunction()
```

are there anyway that i can call function without name of the module like this:

```
ifunction()
```

Comment: What do you mean by _global_ and do you really need it? What is CoreTemplate, a class? Then ifunction would be a method, not a function, and there is no language in which you can call a method without an object or its class name, because that makes no sense.

Comment: yes, CoreTemplate is a class and ifunction is a method. Is it possible to make the method available without specifying its classname?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Does it even make sense to call it without an object? Probably not. Are you maybe looking for a way to create a lambda expression? Look, please motivate your question. Otherwise it's not possible to say whether you simply haven't understood the concept of method invocation or are simply a bit confused by Python specifics.

Comment: If `CoreTemplate` is a class, don't you need to create an instance of it to call the `ifunction()` method -- ie `CoreTemplate().ifunction()`?

Comment: So, a day later, neither we here nor the OP exactly know what the question really was, because we have contradictory input as @martineau clearly illustrated. Hey, OP, could you clarify whether or not `CoreTemplate` is a class, and have you read my request to describe why you think you want such a reference? Because it could be the case that you need something different than what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
from CoreTemplate import CoreTemplate
ifunction = CoreTemplate.ifunction
```

(note the absence of parentheses)

Comment: Are there anyway that i can do this for all function defined in 'CoreTemplate'

Comment: True, but what would an absolute beginner gain from it, except for total iConfusion? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
from CoreTemplate import ifunction

ifunction()
```

Comment: Plan wrong, since inside CoreTemplate there's a class CoreTemplate, as has been clarified.

Answer (score 0):

This should do;

```
from CoreTemplate import CoreTemplate

g = globals()

for atr in dir(CoreTemplate):
    if atr.startswith("_"):
        continue
    g[atr] = getattr(CoreTemplate, atr)
```